# Responsive bar with three divs

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my Wordpress Child Theme (TwentyTwelve) I am creating a bar with a menu, a search form and a social link menu. I had problems to align them properly till I found a solution. I show a table row in css and then three cells (also in css). The code looks like this:

```
#table-row{
display: table-row;
line-height: 44px;
text-align: right;  
}

#menubar{
display: table-cell;
padding-left: 40px;
}
#search-container {
display: table-cell;
}
#menu-social-wrapper{
display: table-cell;
}
```

The markup looks like this:

```
<div id="navigation-container" class="navigation-container">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">

                <div id="table-row">
                    <div id="menubar">
                        <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( '<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></button>
                        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>                    
                    </div>

                    <div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper clear">
                        <div id="searchbox" class="search-box clear">
                            <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Header Widget Area')) : endif;?>
                        </div>
                    </div> 

                    <div id="menu-social-wrapper" class="menu-social-wrapper">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'menu', 'social' ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>    

            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div>
```

This gives me this fine result:

[image]
However when the screen is smaller (in this case 400 px.) I get a wrong result:

[image]

What I want to achieve is this:

```
+------------------------------+
|  Search bar                  |
+------------------------------+
|  Social Icons menu           |
+------------------------------+
|  Menu (toggles, bar icon)    |
+------------------------------+
```

I'm trying for a couple of days now but I haven't found a solution yet.

Please help me out here. 
Note: I am a bit of a newbie so keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Could always look at bootstrap source. They do a great job with being mobile-first and responsive. (I've given up competing with how IE/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari/etc. and find frameworks let me focus on the parts I need to)

Comment: Your problem is "table-row" and "table-cell". You need to change that with media query when you want your 3 divs in column

Comment: you need to use media queries and for small screen sizes change from display:table, to display:block

Answer (score 1):

As always... when I post a question, the answer is coming up. Right before Awashi's comment I figured it out. Indeed a media query was part of the answer and then change the css from
display:table-row and `display:table-cell` to `display:block`.

Had to do some work on margins and padding but now it looks great.

With this another issue was coming up but I'm sure that I can solve it.

[image]

Anyway, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using table-row and table-cell values whe doing what you do. The layout and content of your part of the page is not a table, therefore using display: block or display: inline-block would be more appropriate. Inline-block elements can be aligned as inline content (text-align) and you can give them width (33% for example).

If you want narrow screens to show divs in one column, use media queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just solved the problem. See answer above.